# How to check whether a huge floating point number is an integer?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a very large floating point number (around 20 digits) and I want to check whether it is an integer or not. For example, if I have a number like 154.0 then it is an integer while 154.123123 is not an integer.

I need to check for very huge floating point numbers (20 digits or more) which means I can't first convert it into a long long datatype and see if both of them are same. Please shove me into right direction. I would appreciate answers only in C/C++. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, what's "huge"? If the number is really huge in a sense that the number of digits is greater than the number representable by the mantissa of your floating-point number, then your floating-point number is *always* an integer.

For example, the IEEE 754 double-precision format has a 52-bit mantissa, which is sufficient for about 16 decimal digits. If your numbers have 20 decimal digits then any attempt to squeeze such numbers into a `double` will result in rounding, effectively turning your numbers into "integers".

You mention that your numbers are too large to fit into the `long long` datatype. If you are referring to 64-bit `long long` datatype, then it automatically means that your numbers are so large that they'll never have any fractional part when represented by a typical `double` type, i.e. they will always be "integers" if represented by `double` values.

P.S. Are you are using some exotic floating-point type with an extra-wide mantissa?

Comment: @AndreyT : That's very interesting. And it seems quite obvious too. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

And does that mean that's there's no way to store a floating point number with mantissa having more than 15 digits? 

I would prefer not to use strings as that would complicate matters with arithmetic operations. Is there **ANY** way to accomplish what I need to do?

Comment: @Anubhav: Why do you need to?  What kind of application needs more than 20 digits of precision?

Comment: @Oli - I need to check for a very huge number (stored in a double) that whether it is a square or not. What I'm doing is calculate its square root and check whether its an integer. The square root itself is very huge. Is there any work-around for this problem?

Comment: @Anubhav: The problem here is that your "very huge number" may have already been rounded *before* you try to take its square root.  In general, you are probably better off finding yourself a big-integer library to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah I guess so! I should learn the GMP library now! FYI it was Project Euler problem 94 I was trying to solve! :)

Comment: @Anubhav Sharma: that's the wrong approach. You don't need floating point for that. A simple integer approach : `while(i*i < candidateSquare) { ++i; }`

Answer (score 1):

Just test whether `x == floor(x)`?

Comment: @Nawaz: It is working. All the numbers you tested *are* integers for the reasons I described in my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: How do you know that your first value can be expressed exactly as a `long double`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yet, what you are passing is "integer". Add print out `d` in your `is_integer` function to see what you are *really* passing. Take a look: http://ideone.com/vC1OG

Comment: @AndreyT: Yeah.... I did that. Its printing something else... which is not floating anymore.. thanks..

Comment: @Nawaz: Not floating? Quite the opposite, it is quintessentially floating. What happened to your numbers is exactly what happens with floating-point numbers: since the mantissa has limited width, the number gets rounded.

Comment: I even checked with modf. AndreyT is right! Huge floating point numbers are sadly stored as integers.

Comment: @Anubhav Sharma: I would not say *sadly*. It is just the result of a design tradeoff -- enabling your use case vs. increasing the cost of hardware for all people.

Comment: @Nawaz: The test that you have written is bad. The size of `long double` is missing, while `double` is 64 bits in all platforms, `long double` can be 12 or 16 bytes depending on the platform (IDE one uses 12 bytes). But that is of hardly any importance because the test has a much worse problem: the literals are `double`, so the extra precision in the function will not have any effect, the numbers will be rounded *before* entering the function. Again, that does not modify the output. With 16byte `long double` constants with smaller values (`1798789890898989878.87L`) you will see the effect.